# Restore MySQL with a .mbi file

Tags: mysql

Tengo un back up de una base de datos guardado en un fichero de tipo .mbi. Estoy intentando restaurar la base de datos con ese fichero de backup pero en ningun lugar encuentro como puede restaurarlo, todas las guias son de como crear esa imagen pero no de como importarla.

¿Es posible restaurarla directamente desde ese archivo o es necesario transformarlo en un archivo .sql y hacer el restore?

Los datos del sistema son:
*mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1*

Gracias de ante mano

Comment: Hola lois6b, ya esta traducida la pregunta, disculpa y muchas gracias

Comment: Por curiosidad: ¿por qué redactaste la pregunta en inglés? ¿Llegaste desde [so] o accediste directamente a [es.so]? Nos encontramos con este caso diariamente y nos sería muy útil saber el motivo de la confusión, para poder mostrar la información de manera más clara y explicitar que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en castellano.